# notifydatasetchanged inside fragment with listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

My Fragment with listview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View local=inflater.inflate(R.layout.allist,container,false);
ListView all=(ListView) local.findViewById(R.id.alllistView);
String link=getString(R.string.mainlink);
al=new ArrayList<MyItem>();
ArrayAdapter<MyItem> ad=new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,al);
rlt=new RefreshLinkTask();
rlt.execute(new String[]{link});
all.setAdapter(ad);
return local;
```

My Problem is I can't use notifyDataSetChanged() to listview. It's showing The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListView. The AsyncTask is executed which can be seen on logcat.What I have done wrong?.

Comment: how do you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?.

Comment: I call this way all.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't use notifyDataSetChanged() to listview

so instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` method as `all.notifyDataSetChanged()`(on ListView instance ) you will need to use Adapter instance for calling it as:

```
ad.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

`public void notifyDataSetChanged()`

Added in API level 1

Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

So call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: was about to answer. you answered first. +1.

Comment: Thanks. I was calling on listview.

Comment: @MDEVLP check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

notifyDataSetChanged() should call on your adapter instance not the ListView itself